# Why don't Tintin nor Milou grow bigger in The Shooting Star?

Tags: tintin

The meteor in *The Shooting Star* contains Phostlite, an unknown metal with amazing properties: it makes some things grow huge.

Phostlite seems to affect all biological things on the meteorite:

- The apple core becomes a huge apple tree
- The maggot becomes a huge butterfly
- The small spider becomes a huge spider
- Huge mushrooms appear (and explode)

But somehow Tintin and Milou (Snowy) are not affected. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the comic, prolonged exposure to the metal isn't what causes gigantism (e.g. through radiation), it's more likely that it's down to **ingestion** of the element. Note that the apple and the mushroom absorb the element directly through their roots whereas the spider and the caterpillar likely consumed the metal by [chewing on the plants](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/vegetarian-spider/) or by drinking contaminated water.

In comparison, Tintin and Snowie only consume supplies from the ship itself; sea-biscuits, apples and bottles of water and hence remain unaffected.

[image]

<sub>*Panel Above edited for brevity.*</sub>

Comment: If the spider eats a local fly, then either that fly was normal-sized and therefore not affected itself, or it _was_ affected and should've been gigantic - so how could the spider have eaten it?

Comment: @SQB - Do spiders eat dirt?

Comment: I assumed gigantism was caused by some kind of radiation. But ingestion makes sense.